# Google Cloud SDK gsutil issue: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetCIDIfMetricsEnabled'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

Today our google cloud sdk was upgraded from 121.0.0 to 122.0.0. Subsequently we started seeing this error when we ran `gsutil cp`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/gcloud-cli/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/gcloud-cli/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 48, in main
    os.environ['GA_CID'] = metrics.GetCIDIfMetricsEnabled()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetCIDIfMetricsEnabled'
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized this started when chef upgraded our google cloud sdk to the newest version 122.0.0 that came out today (2016/08/17) (See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes).

Rolling back and installing the previous version from https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-121.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz fixed the issue.